# Convert specific columns into rows in SQL

Tags: sql-server, pivot, rows, col

[image: My query]

This screenshot contain my result, I want to further transpose this query by converting `AMOUNT_BILLED_JANUARY` column into row like this:

| M_ACCOUNTCONTRACT | Bill_Date | Previous1 | Previous2 | Previous3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16959 | 2019-05-13 | 10670.75 | 8580.66 | 6927.59 |
| 16959 | 2019-04-09 | 8580.66 | 6927.59 | 8181.64 |
| 16959 | 2019-03-09 | 6927.59 | 8181.64 | 8751.67 |

Comment: Pivot documentation is available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot). Please include your personal attempt and why it is not working for you. If those column names are dynamic (`Previous1` to `PreviousN` where `N` is not fixed) then you will need "dynamic SQL", plenty of examples on this site already. Or do you just need the first three?

Comment: I just need the first three.

Answer (score 2):

Move your current query into a common table expression (`cte`), but leave the return value of the `row_number()` function in there as an integer. You can use the integer value to fetch the previous rows.

**Sample data**

Reproducing the start of your current result, but with one added column.

```
create table currentResult
(
  M_AccountContract int,
  Bill_Date date,
  Amount_Billed_January decimal(7,2),
  Row_Num nvarchar(15),
  Num int -- include the row_number() function as integer value
);

insert into currentResult (M_AccountContract, Bill_Date, Amount_Billed_January, Row_Num, Num) values
(16959, '2019-05-13', 10670.75, 'previous1', 1),
(16959, '2019-04-09',  8580.66, 'previous2', 2),
(16959, '2019-03-12',  6927.59, 'previous3', 3),
(16959, '2019-02-08',  8181.64, 'previous4', 4),
(16959, '2019-01-11',  8751.67, 'previous5', 5);
-- got lazy here, please post text instead of images next time ;)
```

**Solution**

Use your current result and join it with itself to find the groups of rows that must be pivoted with some easy math (`c2.Num >= c1.Num and c2.Num < c1.Num + 3`) and generate a new row number (`PrevNum`) within each group. Then pivot each group using the new `PrevNum` column.

```
with cte as
(
  -- current query with row_number() integer value goes here
  select *
  from currentResult
),
cte_prev3 as
(
  select c1.M_AccountContract,
         c1.Bill_Date,
         row_number() over(partition by c1.M_AccountContract, c1.Bill_Date order by c2.Num) as PrevNum,
         c2.Amount_Billed_January
  from cte c1
  left join cte c2
    on  c2.M_AccountContract = c1.M_AccountContract
    and c2.Num >= c1.Num
    and c2.Num <  c1.Num + 3
)
select piv.M_AccountContract,
       piv.Bill_Date,
       piv.[1] as Previous1,
       piv.[2] as Previous2,
       piv.[3] as Previous3
from cte_prev3 cp3
pivot (max(cp3.Amount_Billed_January) for cp3.PrevNum in ([1], [2], [3])) piv
order by piv.Bill_Date desc;
```

**Result**

`null` values are the result of the limited sample data.

```
M_AccountContract  Bill_Date   Previous1  Previous2  Previous3
-----------------  ----------  ---------  ---------  ---------
16959              2019-05-13   10670.75    8580.66    6927.59
16959              2019-04-09    8580.66    6927.59    8181.64
16959              2019-03-12    6927.59    8181.64    8751.67
16959              2019-02-08    8181.64    8751.67       null
16959              2019-01-11    8751.67       null       null
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=9094c618fa8e9abbe8d3b101eacdb7d5) to see things in action with intermediate `cte_prev3` results.

Comment: You could just pivot the original `cte` as you have a rownumber already

Comment: Yes, but it goes `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...` across all billing dates instead of `1, 2, 3` for each billing date. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry you're right I missed the extra partitioning clause. But I would just remove the original rownumber and do it using the new instead. Extra point to make here, the original rownumber is non-deterministic, so I think you could teach OP that